# How to categorize entries in Python without O^2 runtime?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

I want to write a Python 3 script to manage my expenses, and I'm going to have a rules filter that says 'if the description contains a particular string, categorize it as x', and these rules will be read in from a text file.

The only way I can think of doing this is to apply str.find() for each rule on the description of each transaction, and break if one is found - but this is a O^2 solution, is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: There's no such thing as `O^2`, there's however `O(n^2)`, but then please define what `n` is.

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil -- DonaldKnuth

Comment: Sounds like the running time will be O(nm) if you have n transactions and m categories

Comment: unless you're buying items at the rate of a couple a minute and you want to run full-year expenses in under a second you're unlikely to notice the difference

Comment: Well, no, I don't have that many transactions/rules. Yes, sorry, it looks like it might be O(nm) after all.
What the hell is up with that hypocrisy, companies expect you to ace such programming challenges when applying for jobs, but when I finally find such a problem in my life that is a good challenge, people throw that 'Premature optimization' quote around.

Comment: @randomshinichi A find it reasonable (well, it depends...) that some company want you to know how to do this. It's _good to know_ how to do this in case you _need_ it. Does that mean it's always good idea? No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strip punctuation from the description, and `split` it into words. Make the words in the description into a `set`, and the categories into another `set`.

Since [sets use dictionaries internally](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) and [dictionaries are built on hash-tables](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C4Kc8xzcA68), *average* membership checking is O(1).

*Only* when a transaction is entered (or changed), intersect both sets to find the categories that apply (if any), and add the categories to your transaction record (`dict`, `namedtuple`, whatever).